# Automatically register users in resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to configure spring security with oauth2, however I am new to this topic and ran into a problem.

I have a spring backend and an angular frontend. I use Azure AD (Authorization code flow with PKCE) for my user authentication (OIDC) and authorization. In my application I have a user table in the database and I want to **save any user that is not present in the database**.

Basically, what this means is that I want all the users who are using my API to be automatically registered (saved in the DB) if they aren't already registered, kinda like an auto registration feature.

What I have tried so far is to configure an ApplicationListener based on AuthenticationSuccessEvent, however I'm running into a problem (I'm assuming due to race condition). When I load the Angular application and login to Azure AD, I get redirected to a page that automatically sends a couple of http requests to the backend. When the first one goes through the filter chain and hits the ApplicationListener, it registers the sees that there is no user with the specified username in the DB and goes and registers him, but by the time that happens the other requests have already gone through the if statement and end up registering the user again. So basically the same user gets registered 6 times and that obviously is not the desired behavior. Below is the ApplicationListener and the SecurityConfig. If you need any other information post a comment and I will update the question.

Also, if you guys know a better way of "auto registering users" feel free to share that as well!

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public MyAuthenticationSuccessListener(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();

        if (!userRepository.findByUsername(((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal()).getClaimAsString("preferred_username")).isPresent()) {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setUsername(((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal()).getClaimAsString("preferred_username"));
            newUser.setName(((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal()).getClaimAsString("given_name"));
            newUser.setSurname(((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal()).getClaimAsString("family_name"));
            if (((JSONArray) ((Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal()).getClaim("roles")).isEmpty()) {
                newUser.setRole(Role.USER);
            } else {
                newUser.setRole(Role.ADMIN);
            }
            userRepository.save(newUser);
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve it with a clean way and how? The below answer seems ok, but I don't want to use native SQL if possible...

Comment: Sadly I haven't solved it, and I don't like the below answer as well, seems more like a hack than a solution. Apparently though there is very little information on how to achieve this, which is weird because I assumed that this is a common feature...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your post, it helped me a bit ^^. To "solve" the issue, I just added a UNIQUE constraint on my Azure Object Id field and when I do "userRepository.save()" I am just catching the exception that occurs.
It still gives me some error logs (which is weird, I couldn't find a way to prevent these logs), but at least the exception is gone. I don't understand why there is no better solution for a problème like this one which should be common. And, it arises only the first time the user log in, so I am gonna do with it while I don't have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a custom INSERT statement for the User entity may work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users(name, role) VALUES (?, ?)"
public class User {
```

Then you would not need to perform a read in Java. You would need a unique constraint on the user name:

```
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

Alternatively, a custom insert on the repository may work (would also require an index on the name for efficiency):

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into User (name,role) values(:name,:role) where (select count(*) from User where name == :name) == 0")
    public int conditionallySaveUser(@Param("name") String name, @Param("role") String role);
}
```

NOTE: only two fields are used for simplicity while the syntax may need adjusting or a native SQL query may have to be created (native=true)

Comment: Isn't there a way to save the users with using security config (like authentication success handler), the Authentication success event or even a custom web filter? I figured doing this on the application level is much cleaner. Is this a rare use case to automatically save users in the DB when working with OAuth? I haven't been able to find anything on the internet regarding this issue

Comment: You code was based on an event listener which is a clean way of doing this. Saving a user (customer) makes sense as user/customer data will be linked to the user id. User id may be subject id from the token or, even better, some other stable id that will not depend on the auth method and auth provider. User here is a business entity and not an auth entity. For example, you may want to maintain user preferences and contact details.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but since I searched for a solution for this and found this post I want to provide you my personal solution. This way you can also add your personal Authorities. In your SecurityConfig, create a Bean like so:

```
private final MyGrantedAuthoritiesConverter myGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(myGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

And then

```
public class MyGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt source) {
        UserEntity user = findOrCreate(source);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        if (user.getSomeAuthority() != null) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getSomeAuthority()));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    private UserEntity findOrCreate(Jwt source) {
        String id = source.getSubject();
        UserEntity user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            String name = source.getClaimAsString("name");
            user = userService.create(id, name);
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

Hope this still helps someone!

Additional docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.4/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction